# ListenHttp Apache NIfi generic basepath

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to use a more generic basepath in the listenHTTP processor are they any way to specify for this webservice to accept all call incoming to port 9090 or specify a more generic basepath, in this case this is possible how can I use this basepath on routeonAttribute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListenHTTP does not write the base path as an attribute so you would not be able to RouteOnAttribute later. That said, I would suggest checking out [HandleHttpRequest](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpRequest/index.html) and [HandleHttpResponse](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpResponse/index.html). These two processors are essentially a more advanced version of ListenHTTP.

There is an "Allowed Paths" property on HandleHttpRequest which will allow you to specify which you want to allow. Also HandleHttpRequest writes "http.context.path" as an attribute for you to use in a RouteOnAttribute later.

You can find an example template [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Example+Dataflow+Templates) under "Hello_NiFi_Web_Service.xml".